# Why is "new swatch" greyed out in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

"New Swatch" is greyed out in Illustrator, but I'd like to use a color.  Why is it greyed out?

[image]

My document color settings are RGB.  Those are the only color settings I know about that might explain this feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you have the "None" swatch selected.

Go to the Color Panel and choose a color- then back to your Swatch Panel and the New Swatch button will be available.

When either the None swatch or the Registration swatch are selected the New Swatch Button will gray out.

Comment: I would like to add, this behavior is because you can not inherit the colors form either of these special colors. (though i dont know why transparent swatch couldn't default to white and registration to RGB black or K 100% for convenience and one less confusion point)